# Stateless Resource Sever effiently validating Facebook tokens

Tags: java, spring, oauth-2.0, access-token, facebook-access-token

I am writing a Resource Server backend for a mobile app front end. The app is responsible for getting a token from Facebook and passing it to the backend for authz, but as they do not use JWT bearer tokens as other providers do (eg. google, apple)... and which Spring has some very nice libraries for...  I have had to write this custom bit to validate the token and collect some basic user information.

This works fairly well, but response time can be variably sluggish if I need to run this for each request to my stateless application. I am considering some form of caching for this token after it has been validated (with a ttl of course)... but am generally curious if there are any established techniques I should be using.

```
@Data
class FacebookDetails {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
}

class Facebook {
  public AuthenticationProvider getAuthenticationProvider() {
    WebClient facebookWebClient = WebClient.create("https://graph.facebook.com/v10.0");

    OpaqueTokenIntrospector introspector =  = token -> {
        Optional<ResponseEntity<FacebookDetails>> maybeResponse = facebookWebClient.get()
                .uri("/me?fields=id,name,email&access_token=" + token)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .retrieve()
                .toEntity(FacebookDetails.class)
                .onErrorResume(e -> Mono.empty())
                .blockOptional(Duration.ofMinutes(1L));

        if (maybeResponse.isEmpty()) {
            throw new BadOpaqueTokenException("token is invalid");
        }

        FacebookDetails details = maybeResponse.get().getBody();
        return details.getPrincipal();
    };

    return new OpaqueTokenAuthenticationProvider(introspector);
  }
}
```

Comment: are you asking for actual implementations/libraries to use, or architectural/technical approaches?

Comment: Either, but more of the second. This just feels like something that would have been solved at this point, so I am just looking for tips. Also I don’t want to make some terrible security mistake.

Answer (score 0):

One could cache the access token as long as it is valid for. To find out how long that is, you could interpret the `expires_in` claim in the JSON response from the Facebook token endpoint, as described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/refreshing/